# fixture.FeatureSpec / withFixture(OneArgTest) issue

Tags: scala, scalatest

I want to share a Database / Knowledge base, for a suite of test. I want it to be available for any test suite. I am using featureSpec

Following the Documentation, I use fixture.FeatureSpec.

As of now i have defined the following:

```
trait InteractionKbFixtureTrait { this: fixture.Suite =>

type FixtureParam = InteractionKB

def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): Unit = {

    val kb = KbFactory.createKb("", "") // create the fixture

    try {

     this.withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(kb)) // "loan" the fixture to the test

    } finally { 

//kb.stop() // clean up the fixture

}

}
```

}

followed by

```
class ExampleSpec extends fixture.FeatureSpec with InteractionKbFixtureTrait {


}
```

I get the following error :

Type overriding method withFixture in trait Suite of type (test: ExampleSpec.this.OneArgTest) org.scalatest.Outcome; 
method withFixture in trait InteractionKbFixtureTrait of type (test: ExampleSpec.this.OneArgTest) Unit has incompatible type InteractionKbFixtureTrait.scala

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `def withFixture` should return type `org.scalatest.Outcome`, whereas your `def withFixture` is returning `Unit`. Error message is saying that quite clearly.

So for fixing it you need to change line:

```
def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): Unit = {
```

like so:

```
def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): org.scalatest.Outcome = {
```